# Why child attributes can be called in parent class in Python and what is the best practice?

Tags: python

I guess this piece of code shouldn't work, but it works:

```
class Parent():
    def print_child(self):
        print(self.child_attr)

class Child(Parent):
    child_attr = "Some text goes here"

child = Child()
child.print_child()
```

So the next question: what is the best practise?

1. leave it as it is (it seems not a good idea)
2. Define parent like:

   class Parent():

   ```
   child_attr = None

   def print_child(self):

       print(self.child_attr)
   ```
3. Define parent like:

   class Parent():

   ```
   def print_child(self, child_attr):

       print(child_attr)
   ```

Comment: Attribute lookups (like everything else in python) happen during runtime. And at that time, the object does indeed have that attribute - so your code works. As for best practice, `print_child` should simply be in the `Child` class'

Comment: Thank you. What if I need the same logic for same attributes of all child classes? What for do I need the same "print_child" (print_child is just an example) in every class? It's not DRY. I guess it's the way Mixin works in Django.

Comment: If the same attribute is there in each child class, add that attribute to the parent.

Comment: Thanks. Number 2 in my question, right?